# Python: rolling.apply() gives TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, typeerror

**My function:**

```
def f(x):
    print(len(x)) 
    return

test.set_index('exchTstamp',inplace=True)
test['fit_x'].rolling('1.0S').apply(lambda x: f(list(x)))
```

On running below code on a time-indexed dataframe, I am getting the following error:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-151-4de6334ec332> in <module>()
> ----> 1 g=testTbt['fit_x'].rolling('1.0S').apply(lambda x: f(list(x)))
> 
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.pyc in
> apply(self, func, raw, args, kwargs)    1701     def apply(self, func,
> raw=None, args=(), kwargs={}):    1702         return super(Rolling,
> self).apply(
> -> 1703             func, raw=raw, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)    1704     1705     @Substitution(name='rolling')
> 
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.pyc in
> apply(self, func, raw, args, kwargs)    1010     1011         return
> self._apply(f, func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,
> -> 1012                            center=False, raw=raw)    1013     1014     def sum(self, *args, **kwargs):
> 
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.pyc in
> _apply(self, func, name, window, center, check_minp, **kwargs)
>     878                     result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
>     879                 else:
> --> 880                     result = calc(values)
>     881 
>     882             if center:
> 
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.pyc in calc(x)
>     872                 def calc(x):
>     873                     return func(x, window, min_periods=self.min_periods,
> --> 874                                 closed=self.closed)
>     875 
>     876             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
> 
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.pyc in f(arg,
> window, min_periods, closed)    1007             return
> libwindow.roll_generic(    1008                 arg, window, minp,
> indexi,
> -> 1009                 closed, offset, func, raw, args, kwargs)    1010     1011         return self._apply(f, func, args=args,
> kwargs=kwargs,
> 
> pandas/_libs/window.pyx in pandas._libs.window.roll_generic()
> 
> TypeError: a float is required
```

I basically want to do some calculations on a rolling base, like calculating the exponential moving average. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/104ngrhwXqgQa1fjMWYMiH5g2Vt8SzO9G/view)

Comment: I'm not that good with `pandas`, but it seems you'd want to have the function `f` to return a value.

Comment: try droping the .0 and use 1s insted

Comment: KeyError: 'fit_x'

Comment: You are applying `len(x)`over the whole dataframe while using `rolling`, since you have multiple columns. What is your goal exactly? Since right now it does not make sense

Comment: Also, are you sure that your column `exchTstamp` is correctly typed into a `datetime64` pandas type? When reading the csv, this could be done with the arguments `parse_dates` and if needed `date_parser` ([read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Comment: Thanks @EmilVatai , it was the missing return statement that was causing the error

Comment: @Erfan since I've used apply function on the `fit_x` columns, therefore the function f will operate only on that set of values. I wanted to calculated expoenential moving avg on a rolling basis, as mentioned in question

Comment: @ndclt yes in the main script I have first performed the conversion using python datetime library, the csv uploaded was just for sample purposes for the SO community

Comment: You have the up arrow to say thank you. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you'd want to have the function `f` to return a value.  `apply` is similar to `map` and it needs to return a value.